# Save subscribed values to a variable and show them 10 at a time

Tags: angular

I have a search service like this ::

```
public getAllData(): Observable<UInfo> {
return this.http.get<any>('/assets/data/info-data.json');
}
```

And on my component.ts I have this :

```
  public getData(){
this.searchService.getAllData().subscribe(results => {
  this.infoData= results['data'];
  this.displayData=this.infoData.slice(0,10);
});
```

}

Andn I call getData() on Init..
What I need to do is, show 10 rows at a time, so I need to slice infoData(0,10) and on every scroll to add 10 more.

This is what I've tried :

```
 onScroll(){
       if(this.allInfoData.length < this.infoData.length){
   let len=this.allInfoData.length;
   for(this.i=len;this.i<=len+20;this.i++){
  this.allInfoData.push(this.infoData[this.i]);
   }
   }
 }
```

But the thing is on ngOnInit, the getAllData function already returns every row there is.

How do I store all data in a variable so that onInit I only display 10, and then on every scroll I add more ?

```
 <div class="col-md-11 tableDiv" infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="2" 
  [infiniteScrollThrottle]="100" (scrolled)="onScroll()">
 <div >
 <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead class="table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Color</th>          
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
 <tr *ngFor="let row of displayData">
      <td>{{row.Date| date:'MM/dd/yy'}} </td>
      <td>{{row.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{row.Color}}</td>         
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all the results in one variable and store the displayed results in another.

```
this.searchService.getAllData().subscribe(results => {
    this.infoData = results['data']; // store all data
    this.displayData = this.infoData.slice(0,10); // store display data
});
```

Then in your `onScroll` method slice what you want to display

```
onScroll(){
   let currentLength = this.displayData.length;

   // you probably want some more logic here to determine if the user is near the bottom of the results
   if(currentLength < this.infoData.length){
       this.displayData = this.infoData.slice(0, currentLength + 10);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That logic is implemented by ngx-infinite scroll, but quick question.
Here your display Data will get 0 to 10, and then 0 to 20 and then 0 to 30.
I was thinking on this function to only Append +10 and then +10 to the sliced initial object

Comment: @ArEmil yea, you can definitely slice `10-20`, `20-30`, etc.. and append those to your display data `let newItems = this.infoData.slice(currentLength, currentLength + 10); this.displayData.push(...newItems);`

Comment: Thank you. I do push and on console log when on the onScroll function when I print out displayData, it pushes those values.
But they don't get appended on the table. Where I have an *ngFor="let data of displayData "
Doesn't display data change when on push, so it should also show them on the table ?

Comment: @ArEmil can you post your html code that has the ngFor?

Comment: @ArEmil nothing stands out at first glance. Can you compare to this [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wr86w9?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Do I need to have a Loop on ngOnInit ?

Comment: @ArEmil na, you don't. I was just doing it to build my data. but your data would come directly from an api

Comment: Yeah, I just analyzed your code. 
And I've done the exact same thing. 
When I print out on console.log after I've pushed it..it prints out correctly, +10,+10 more.
But the table doesn't change :|

Comment: @ArEmil hmm you may have to run change detection manually. Try injecting [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) and running `this.changeDetectorRef.detechChanges();` after you push to your array.

Comment: There's no error. It doesn't show anything on the console.log.

Comment: @ArEmil which console.log?

Comment: Hey. When I write : 
`this.displayData = this.infoData.slice(0, currentLength + 10);` instead of the push, it does display the data.
But when I have the push, it doesn't.
Maybe after I have `this.displayData=push(...newitems)` , I need some way to have this.displayData= something ?

Comment: @ArEmil is your table in a child component?  the slice method is working because this.displayData is receiving a new array so angular detects the changes. Where as with push the array is the same so angular might not be seeing the changes. I was hoping the change detection would work. Could you create a simple stack blitz that recreates the issue?

Comment: @ArEmil did you fork the stackblitz? That link is the same as my stackblitz

Comment: @ArEmil this seems to be the same code as mine. Can you put the code in with the child component.

Comment: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwzwtf) Sorry, I had overwritten my code.

But here it doesn't show a problem. And I have the same exact thing done in my code..
But it doesn't detect it

Comment: @ArEmil everything is labeled correctly? Proper variables are used? Do the first 10 results show?

Comment: Yes. The first 10 results show.. When I put console.log(displayData) after I've pushed, on scroll down ...they show there.
Just the table won't get updated

Comment: @ArEmil there must be some difference between your code and the stackblitz. You are using `this.displayData` not `displayData` right